# Can I use a timeout to limit the number of rows returned?

Tags: sql-server

Instead of using `TOP` I'd like to use **time** to limit the number of rows returned by a query.

I have attempted to achieve this with `DATEDIFF` and `SYSDATETIME`:

```sql
DECLARE @Start DATETIME2(7) = SYSDATETIME()

SELECT *
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE DATEDIFF(SECOND, @Start, SYSDATETIME()) <= 1
```

But in practice this exceeds the time limit and returns every row in the table.

Can anyone suggest a better way?

**Context:** I was looking for a way to evenly share system resources between various recurring update tasks, some of which are more resource-intensive than others (usually CPU-bound). I have actually solved this problem in a different way, but I'm still curious to see what's possible. I am using SQL Server 2022 Express Edition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea doesn't work because the 'current time' functions like `SYSDATETIME` are treated as *[runtime constants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/conor_cunningham_msft/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions)* for the duration of the statement. A single value is recorded just before the statement starts executing and the cached value used every time the function is evaluated.

Even if it did work the way you hoped, SQL Server would continue to test the predicate on every row in the table rather than stopping when the time limit was up.

SQL Server doesn't provide a way to stop execution neatly after a specified time in a way conceptually similar to [`SET LOCK_TIMEOUT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-lock-timeout-transact-sql).

Some clients do offer a timeout facility, but those typically just send a 'cancel' command (attention signal) to the server at the appropriate moment.

For curiosity's sake only, you could do something horrible and inefficient like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM <some big table or query>
WHERE
    1 = 
    CASE
        WHEN
        (
            SELECT 
                DER.total_elapsed_time
            FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS DER 
            WHERE
                DER.session_id = @@SPID
                AND DER.request_id = CURRENT_REQUEST_ID()
        ) < 100  -- milliseconds, roughly
        THEN 1   -- ok to continue
        ELSE 1/0 -- fail and bail
    END;
```

which throws a "Divide by zero error encountered" error, but I'd encourage you to rethink the whole thing. It's unreliable anyway, since SQL Server doesn't guarantee the number or timing of expression evaluations. It happens to 'work' for simple cases.

You could also create a scalar function (ugh!) to return a current time on each call, but this is even more inefficient.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.LocalNow ()
RETURNS datetime2(7)
WITH SCHEMABINDING, INLINE = OFF
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN SYSDATETIME();
END;
```

There are many creatively bad ways to attempt this. Resist!

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is: **No.**

This is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I use a timeout to limit the number of rows returned?

It's not reasonably possible to do something like this, no.

> I was looking for a way to evenly share system resources between various recurring update tasks, some of which are more resource-intensive than others (usually CPU-bound).

Even if it were reasonably possible to do, here's a reason why it would still be nonsensical: One of the first things that happens when you execute a query is the SQL Engine comes up with something called an execution plan, which is a series of operations it plans to do in order to process the query. Inclusive in that execution plan is a request to the server for the resources that the SQL Engine thinks it'll need to process that execution plan. The server then grants the resources it's reasonably able to, to try to meet that request.

Before even a single row has been returned from the query, [Memory is already being granted](https://erikdarlingdata.com/starting-sql-memory-grants-in-execution-plans/) and reserved to service that query. By default, there's a [max limit up to 25% of the Memory](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/understanding-sql-server-memory-grant/ba-p/383595) on the server that can be granted to a single query. (Yep, that's a lot for one query.) So, even if you could implement a query timeout for a specific query, it wouldn't achieve what your actual goal is - improved hardware resource sharing.

The best way to accomplish that instead, is to understand what your query is doing. Reading the execution plan itself is a great way to do that. Tuning any significant bottlenecks in the query - which can sometimes involve index tuning, re-writing the query itself, or re-architecting the overall process and / or design of the database in more extreme cases, is how you can improve server resources.

For certain scenarios, adjusting the batch size of the records being processed (either by a `TOP` or even better by applicable predicates to filter the dataset down earlier on) and sometimes taking an iterative approach to process all batches is helpful for letting the server *breathe* more. But it's important to understand if you actually have a hardware contention problem to begin with before implementing such an approach.